# mongoose model update query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

i have this mongoose schemas

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var imageModel = new Schema({
    url: {type: String}
});
var albumModel = new Schema({
    name: {type:String},
    images: [imageModel]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Album",albumModel);
```

and one instance of this schema is

```
    { 
     _id: 55ba2588e8e0f5d80f752889,
     name: 'album1',
     __v: 0,
    images:
     [ { 
        url: 'images_uploaded/photo1.gif',
        _id: 55ba2588e8e0f5d80f75288e 
       },
       {  
         url: images_uploaded/photo2.jpg',
        _id: 55ba2588e8e0f5d80f75288d
       }]
    }
```

I would remove from album the images that not exist in other json object that come from user request

```
     console.log(req.body)

     {
       _id: 55ba2588e8e0f5d80f752889,
       name: 'album1',
       images:
        [{  
            url: images_uploaded/photo2.jpg',
           _id: 55ba2588e8e0f5d80f75288d
        }]
    }
```

should remove photo1.gif from a subdocument

I have tried with

```
 album.images.pull({"_id":"55ba2588e8e0f5d80f75288e "});
```

And this work fine, but when i use $nin operator

```
 var ids = [];
 for(var i=0; i< req.body.images.length; i++)
 {
      ids.push(req.body.images[i]._id);
 }

 req.album.images.pull({"_id":{$nin: ids}});
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are calling the method at `Array.protoype.pull`, not from mongoose's `pull`. But Here is how you can make pull from nested objects from array.

```
var Album = require("albumModel");

....
var ids = req.body.images.map(function(image){ return image._id });

Album.update({}, { $pull: { images: { $elemMatch: { _id: { $nin: ids } } } } }).exec(function(err) {
  // Do something
});

....
```